# What does 'bank'ing a register mean?

Tags: arm, cpu

Reading 'ARM Architecture' on Wikipedia and found the following statement:

> Registers R0-R7 are the same across all CPU modes; they are never
>   banked.
>
> R13 and R14 are banked across all privileged CPU modes except system
>   mode.

What does banking a register mean?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Register banking refers to providing multiple copies of a register at the same address.

Taken from section 1.4.6 of the arm [docs](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/srg/han/ACS-P35/zynq/arm_gic_architecture_specification.pdf)

The term is referring to a solution for the problem that not all registers can be seen at once.

> There is a different register bank for each processor mode. The banked registers give rapid context switching for dealing with processor exceptions and privileged operations.

If your looking for a more theoretical reasoning, I recommend [this](http://scale.eecs.berkeley.edu/papers/bankedreg-isca2003.pdf) paper.
Edit: A much deeper answer than mine is given [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102742/what-does-banking-mean-when-applied-to-registers/102743#102743)

Comment: [The ARM Instruction Set - ARM University Program](http://simplemachines.it/doc/arm_inst.pdf) pdf is also a useful reference.  I think the ARM.com link in this question is dead and/or requires registration.

Comment: The ISCA paper you linked refers to a different meaning of banking--that kind of banking is used to reduce access port count and is often called pseudo-porting when used for caches. The ARM register banking is meant to simplify and speed exception handling. (MIPS provides a similar feature called Shadow Register Sets in which the entire set of GPRs is replicated; Itanium provides 16 shadow registers out of 127 [+ zero register] GPRs.) Some RISCs used an ABI that provided one or more scratch registers that could be overwritten by exception handlers without saving.

Comment: @paul can you explain the concept of banked registers in detail

Comment: @UchiaItachi Does [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/102743) help? (Since the other use of the term banking does not apply to this question, I asked and answered a question on EE.SE. If my answer is inadequate, others at EE.SE may provide their own or edit my answer [it is community wiki]. [I fear the explanation is lacking, but it may help.])

Answer (score 15):

When the processor enters an exception, the *banked registers* are switched automatically with another set of these registers.

Virtually, the exception handler routine doesn't have to save these registers on the stack to prevent them from being clobbered later on (by the exception handler functions). The processor just keeps a safe copy of that set; and will restore the original set on exception return.

Answer (score 2):

This clip explains it well
https://youtu.be/7LqPJGnBPMM?t=1419

Banked registers are registers which are not needed and accessible by the current execution mode. When the execution mode changes, the registers needed for the new mode will become usable.